# How to send notification from App to App in Firebase 3

Tags: objective-c, iphone, notifications, firebase

I am Using new firebase https://firebase.google.com/ , is it possible to send notification from one app to another app like oneSignel (https://onesignal.com/ is third party tool for send notification) ??

if yes,  then how we can implement app to app notification ??

i am checking firebase document but not getting clearly how to done ?? (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Comment: I would like to know this as well

Answer (score 0):

I have been spending a great deal of time on this now trying to figure out what is the solution. The best answer I have is that Firebase doesn't offer device-to-device notification included and you need to integrate another app server (basically a small middle app running on an external server) which listens to changes in Firebase nodes; e.g, ChildAdded, etc, and then fires off notification via FCM or GCM which is the older version of FCM now.

Since the Firebase Documentation hints you need XMPP protocol for upstream messaging if that's what you would want. Otherwise you can use html. You can run the middle app or as Firebase calls it app server in App Engine which is a google product. I am in the process of making this happen myself. If I get anywhere will update this with more info.

An brief tutorial can be found [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html) on what to expect.
Hope this helps.